# SQL Update by Column Index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I have `Products` table with columns `ProductID, ProductName, ProductSalePrice, ProductBuyPrice` (there are many more columns tbh.)

Usually you can update database like this :

```
Update Products 
Set ProductSalePrice = 54 
where ProductID = 12947
```

But what I want is, use update command with column index instead of column name. Like this :

```
Update Products 
Set "Third Column" = 54 
where ProductID = 12947
```

How to update table by column index? Any suggestions?

**Edit :** it appears SQL Server doesn't have natural column order for query use. Which I wrongly guessed for my approach. I wanted to have a option, as like as the code above but without having work on database.

**Edit 2 :** I've accepted the answer below since it seems impossible to do without work on database. If new approach comes, I may change the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: I'm creating a windows form application which has different forms for different functions. Each of them is like Product management, customer management, sales management and all those have their database tables. And then I use datagridview on those forms, when user doubleClick the cell, user can make changes. Whenever user clicks a cell, my sql commands will be like Update Table Set ClickedColumnIndex = enteredvalue where PrimaryID = CurrentRow.Cell[0](which is uniq ID per table) etc.. so 1 function for all update needs. (in a hard way but I love to being in full controll I guess).

Comment: Please add details to the question, not in a comment. Also, describe the end goal, not the method by which you were thinking of achieving it.

Comment: @trailmax Well I guessed there was a natural column order by SQL itself.

Comment: @OzanAyten Yes, there is such thing, but it is not meant to be used in queries. The same way you can store column name in a hidden zero row in datagrid, and use that for updates.

Comment: @trailmax Ah I see,  I'll think a new way. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: This is not a horrible idea. Id say it would be a very nice feature. Imagine you have to a cross tab type table structure and you have to update sales numbers for each month for a group of products.  If it were possible to update via column index, you could write a loop.  As it is, you have write 12 update statements and name the field.

When people post a question here, they are really just looking for help. If you don't have an answer, no response is called for. Telling someone 'horrible idea' is unproductive at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *really* need this, you could use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table to find the columns and their order (using `ORDINAL_POSITION`). Then build a dynamic query with the update statement.

```
declare @columnNum int
SET @columnNum = 3

declare @column nvarchar(100)

set @column = 
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        COLUMN_NAME
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Products'
        AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @columnNum
)

declare @sql nvarchar(500)

set @sql = 'Update Products Set ' + @column + ' = 54 where ProductID = 12947'

sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I was mistaken at my question, sorry. If you can read the edit part you'll notice. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Build a query in a string variable, then EXECUTE it ([more on EXECUTE @variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)):

```
declare @update as varchar(max) = 'update Products set Column' + @columnNumber + '= .....'
exec @update
```

Needing this is a hint that you'd better redesign your database, but I understand that it's not always possible.

Comment: I suspect he doesn't actually have columns named `Column3` or whatever.

Comment: @DourHighArch I don't have column Named Column3. What I want to mean is   Update Products Set "3rd Column" = 54 where ProductID = 12947.

Comment: Btw, Doesn't SQL have a column order itself that we can use ?

Comment: @OzanAyten how about building the query from C# (pasting a column name into your update)?

Comment: No, columns in SQL are unordered so what you are thinking of won't work. There is a way to get the column ordinal from TSQL, but before I explain how to do that I'll need a more detailed explanation of what you think you are accomplishing because right now I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Well there is many ways to do around it. My point was to avoid all typing and doing all works via ColumnIndex. If I can't achieve that I'll do it on long and and actually normal way.

Comment: @Ozan you should explain what “avoid all typing” means and why you think “doing all works via ColumnIndex” would help. I suspect there is a much easier way of getting what you want, but I don't understand what you think you are accomplishing.

Comment: @DourHighArch Thank you for your concern. I'm kind of aware there is  easy way to accomplish this. But what I want is different and I don't have a way to explain it right now.( kind of tired ) If there is no natural column order by sql. It will be additional coding on database, so I'm going to accomplish it in a another way.